Netsuite rest api transform SO to item Fulfillment error: You must have at least one valid line item for this transaction
Netsuite rest api transform SO to item Fulfillment
I keep having this error message for a long while which drive me super crazy right now. Does anyone has ideas how to get rid of it?

Error Message: "Error while accessing a resource. You must have at
least one valid line item for this transaction"

Below is my code:
response1 = self.client_controller.post(url='https://XXXXXX.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder/{XXXX}/!transform/itemFulfillment', headers=self.headers, data=json.dumps(item_fullfil_obj))

        item_fullfil_obj = {
            "createdDate":"2024-06-05",
            "createdFrom":{
                "id":"5325997"
            },
            "custbody_bv_employee":{
                "id":"5188"
            },
            "customForm":{
                "id":"183" 
            },
            "department": {
                "id":"1"
            },
            "entity":{
                "id":"318"
            },
            "exchangeRate":1.0,
            "location":{
                "id":"609"
            },
            "shipstatus":"C",
            "status":"C",
            "tranDate":"2024-06-03",
            "subsidiary":{
                "id":"2"
            },
            "item":{
                "items": [
                    {
                        "class":{
                            "id":"43"
                        },
                        "department":{
                            "id":"1"
                        },
                        "excludeFromRateRequest":False,
                        "inventoryDetail":{
                            "inventoryAssignment":{
                                "items":[
                                    {
                                        "internalId":2820203,
                                        "inventoryDetail":2821220,
                                        "inventoryStatus":{
                                            "id":"1"
                                        },
                                        "quantity":1.0,
                                        "quantityAvailable":334.0
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "item":{
                                "id":"2525"
                            },
                            "quantity":1.0,
                            "location":{
                                "id": "609"
                            },
                            "toLocation": {
                                "id":"-1"
                            },
                            "unit":"1"
                        },
                        "item":{
                            "id":"2525"
                        },
                        "itemFxAmount":29.9,
                        "itemName":"BV-BA1",
                        "itemReceive":True,
                        "itemType":"InvtPart",
                        "itemUnitPrice":29.9,
                        "itemUpc":"813076020380",
                        "line":0,
                        "location":{
                            "id":"609"
                        },
                        "orderLine":4,
                        "quantity":1.0,
                        "quantityRemaining":1.0,
                        "quantityRemainingDisplay":1.0,
                        "units":"1",
                        "unitsDisplay":"PC"

                    }
                ]
            },
            "orderId":5325997,
            "orderType":"SalesOrd",
            "package":{
                "items":[{
                    "packageWeight":4.0
                }]
            },
            "tranDate":"2024-06-05"
        }


I also tried the below, it returned the same error.
{ "item":{ "items":[ { "orderLine":1, "location":609, "itemreceive": true }  ] }}

Can anyone help with this?
